# How to use the directive with the button click in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have directive named openDialog as follows. How can I use it from the view with the button click? Here is my code for the directive

```
app.directive('openDialog', ['ngDialog', function (ngDialog) {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
           var openDialog = function () {

               ngDialog.open({
                   //template: $attrs.openDialog,
                   template: 'src/app/reservation/addReview.html',
                   //ngDialog.open({ template: 'src/app/reservation/addReview.html'}),
                   scope: $scope,
                   showClose: false,
                   closeByEscape:true
               });
           };
           $element.on('click', openDialog);
       }
   };
}]);
```

Comment: By applying the corresponding attribute to an element (as it's attribute-based).

Comment: I checked Your event, it is working , problem is in ngDialog.open part.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```js
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <mydirc></mydirc>
    <button ng-click="clickMe()">call clickMe()</button>
</div>

app.directive('mydirc', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.clickMe= function() {
                alert('inside click');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want to make a different html page to pop up with the button click.

Comment: You can use the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)  Its a middleware which can be used to enable the cors with various options.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is right.

```js
var app = angular.module('temp',['ngDialog']);
 app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope,$http,ngDialog){
  $scope.label = "ME ANGULAR, gaga!"
 });

 app.directive('openDialog', ['ngDialog', function (ngDialog) {
  return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
         var openDialog = function () {

             ngDialog.open({
                 template: 'firstDialog',
                 
                 scope: $scope,
                 showClose: false,
                 closeByEscape:true
             });
         };

         $element.on('click', openDialog);
     }
  }; 
 }]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ng-keypress-production</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/css/ngDialog.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/css/ngDialog-theme-default.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/css/ngDialog-theme-flat.css">

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/js/ngDialog.min.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="temp">
 <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <label>{{label}}</label>
  <br/>
  <button open-Dialog>Clickme</button>
 </div>
</body>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="firstDialog">
 <div class="ngdialog-message">
  <h1>Hello</h1><i>I'm ufa, you loaded me</i>
 </div>
</script>
</html>
```